# Use csv file to sort files into folders

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a .csv file that has the list of all subjects and what group they belong to (in addition to other information, but only these two columns are important for this situation).

```
Subject    Group    Age
Subject1   A        ...
Subject2   B        ...
Subject3   C        ...
Subject4   D        ...
Subject5   A        ...
...
```

And my directory (let's call it Database) currently looks like this (A~D are folder names):

```
-Database
    - A
    - B
    - C
    - D
    - Subject1_MRI_3T_Ph.nii
    - Subject2_MRI_3T_Ph.nii
    - Subject3_MRI_3T_Ph.nii
    - Subject4_MRI_3T_Ph.nii
    - Subject5_fMRI_Axial_Se.nii

..
```

My goal is to read the .csv file to get two strings (Subject and Group) and move the files to their respective groups like this:

```
-Database
    - A
        - Subject1_MRI_3T_Ph.nii
        - Subject5_fMRI_Axial_Ph.nii
    - B
        - Subject2_MRI_3T_Ph.nii
    - C
        - Subject3_MRI_3T_Ph.nii
    - D
        - Subject4_MRI_3T_Ph.nii
```

I've tried using pandas library to sort the data, but I got stuck on trying to use that information to tell the os to move the files.

```py
import glob
import os
import shutil
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

filename = '/home/Desktop/.../csvfile.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename)

df = df.sort_values('Subject', ascending=True)
df = df[['Subject' , 'Group']]
print(df)
```

I know that the following two lines output the subject name and the group name respectively...

print(df.iloc[0,0])

`= Subject1`

print(df.iloc[0,1])

`= A`

but it doesn't seem like you can specifically refer to "df.iloc[0,0]", and do the following

```
for x in df.iloc[] #or
#for x in df[['Subject']]
```

Is there a simpler way of doing this? Maybe pandas isn't what I am looking for?